# How to use PersistedGrantDbContext to select PersistedGrant

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I want to get data like this:

```
var persistedGrants = await _PersistedGrantDbContext.PersistedGrants.ToListAsync();
```

This is my config:

```
services.AddDbContext<AccountDbContext>(options =>
                        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))
                    .AddDbContext<PersistedGrantDbContext>(options =>
                        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)));
```

But I have a mistake:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Options.OperationalStoreOptions'
>   while attempting to activate
>   'IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.DbContexts.PersistedGrantDbContext'.

What should I go to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I have resolved my problem. I was missed `services.AddIdentityServer().AddOperationalStore`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to call the database directly, use the provided stores instead.

In this case you can use *IPersistedGrantStore*:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IPersistedGrantStore _store;

    public MyClass(IPersistedGrantStore store)
    {
        _store = store;
    }

    public async Task Something(string sub)
    {
        var persistedGrants = await _store.GetAllAsync(sub);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah I have resolved my problem. I was missed `services.AddIdentityServer().AddOperationalStore`. And i have to use `PersistedGrantDbContext` to get all data in `PersistedGrants` table. Thanks